# Defining locked start and end points on turbulent splines in Animation Nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, animation-nodes, splines

I'm attempting to make an animated "sound wave" effect using AN. So far I have the bouncing spline looking the way I want it --

[image]

How do you define specific points along the spline to NOT move (I'd like to make the start and end points stationary, and also have control of two points in the middle so I can place something in the center)?

These are my splines so far:
[image]
[image]